# Изучение Java. Первая программа для хорошего старта

Tags: java

Вопрос в следующем.

Есть требования:

- знание Java EE, Ajax, Web-Services, XML/XSLT, ORM/SQL
- опыт применения ООП
- знание GWT, UML, JMS, JNI, Spring

Есть цель: Во всем этом разобраться ровно настолько, чтобы можно было смело идти на собеседование и знать, что всё будет ОК в дальнейшем. До сего момента на Java не кодил.

Если информация будет полезна, ТО: Из вышеприведенного списка имел дело со всем, что напрямую не связано с Java (Ajax, XML, SQL ...). В своей практике применял C, Delphi, PHP (он же сейчас мой хлеб насущный и, мягко говоря, поднадоел), JS и было дело на ассемблере либу писал.

Вопрос вот, собственно, в чем. Нужен "быстрый" старт. Для этого сейчас сижу читаю "Thinking in Java" и параллельно хочу писать какое-нибудь (вообще говоря неважно какое, желательно связанную в web и штуками из списка в начале вопроса) приложение к JRE, дабы в голове лучше укладывалось.

Чего начать писать такого, чтоб охватить как можно больше из того списка? Также интересно узнать от Java разработчиков как они до такой жизни "докатились"=) Как говорится опыт из первых рук.

Comment: Советую [этот](http://www.skipy.ru) блог, не пожалеете.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сколько времени готовы потратить на это все?
Вы понимаете, что после С++/PHP придется немного переломить свой мозг, потому что программисты на java, которые пишут в стиле С++ - не нужны.
Из своего опыта - после многих лет С++(серверная часть) предложили вести проект на Java (для телефонов). До этого java видел только, но не писал. И ничего, почитывают книги на досуге (вначале читал Эккеля Thinking in Java - но как то она медленна, теперь читаю Нортона).

Переключится можно, главное иметь проект и хорошего наставника, который будет отвечать на глупые вопросы и делать критику кода.
Также рекомендую полистать [Java Programming for Kids, Parents and Grandparents](http://myflex.org/books/java4kids/java4kids.htm) - она есть и в русском переводе и бесплатная.

Но что бы все было ок, нужно либо талант, либо везение, либо упорная работа. Думаю, за несколько упорных месяцев изучения нормальный программист может переключится на java.

Comment: Планирую в течение года чувствовать себя уверенно в Java. Грустно, что в сутках не 40 часов. А мозг у меня гибкий=) Не раз "ломался"

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте пройти курс "[Студенческий отдел кадров](http://java-course.ru/students/students.php)". Он уже многим помог вникнуть в мир java web-приложений . А качестве домашнего задания, перепишите его на GWT ).